# how to remove my option using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi good morning programmers . i have created one form using html . when user select the number of person according to that number that much of the age and name box will be open at the same time i have one link to remove that boxes .

the html code is :

```
<div class="selectContainer">
    <label for="name">Number Of Person:</label>
    <select id="ddTest" name="no_person">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="Option1">1</option>
        <option value="Option2">2</option>
        <option value="Option3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="hidden isOption1">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option1">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
<div class="hidden isOption2">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
    <div class="hidden isOption3">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option3">remove</a>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         <br>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         <br>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
        </div>
```

And the script is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ddTest").change(function() {         
        var value = $("#ddTest option:selected").val();
        if (value === '') return;
        var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

        //displays the selected option div
        theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");

        //disbales the selected option
        $("#ddTest option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
            $(this).val('');
        });  

        $("div a.remove").click(function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('rel');
            var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
            //enables the disabled option
            $("#ddTest option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
            //hides the selected option div
            $(this).parent().slideUp(function() { $(this).addClass("hidden"); });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Output: when i select number of person 2 then 2 box for name and 2 box for age will come along with the remove link

problem: the problem is when i click remove link of the first option then it will not only remove the first option but all so removing second option . how to avoid this ?

thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two basic mistakes in your code:
1. You forgot to add div 
2. You mentioned option 3 twice which is removing both second and third options in single click

Comment: bro i need one more help . how can i change the option value in selectContainer div ?

Comment: by default its  <option value="Option1">1</option> but i want like  this <option value="1">1</option>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some issues in your HTML. I've editing the following and it works as expected:

```
<div class="selectContainer">
    <label for="name">Number Of Person:</label>
    <select id="ddTest" name="no_person">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="Option1">1</option>
        <option value="Option2">2</option>
        <option value="Option3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="hidden isOption1">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option1">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
<div class="hidden isOption2">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
<div class="hidden isOption3">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option3">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
```

Comment: self closing input tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Javascript solution:-

```
<script>
    function Option1() {
    var name = document.getElementById("ddTest");
    if (name.length > 0) {
        name.remove(name.length-1);
    }
}
function Option2() {
    var age = document.getElementById("ddTest");
    if (age.length > 0) {
        age.remove(age.length-1);
    }
 }
</script>
```

Don't forget to add this one:-

```
<form>
<select id="ddTest" size="4">
  <option>name</option>
  <option>age</option>
</select>
</form>

<button onclick="Option1()">Remove</button>
<button onclick="Option2()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the Select box in Jquery. i.e.

```
HTML_option1 = '<a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >';

HTML_option2 = ' <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>';

$("#ddTest").change(function(){         

value = $(this).val();
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)
{
  HTML_option1 += HTML_option1;
  HTML_option2 += HTML_option2;
}

$("#Youroption1_id").html(HTML_option1);
$("#Youroption1_id").slideDown();
$("#Youroption2_id").html(HTML_option2);
$("#Youroption2_id").slideDown();

 });
```

Make sure when you apply Jquery on the dynamically added HTML you should use .live function instead of click/change/blur.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either modify the DOM as suggested by applejack or modify the click event to:

```
  $("#ddTest").change(function() {         
    var value = $("#ddTest option:selected").val();
    if (value === '') return;
    var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

    //displays the selected option div
    theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");

    //disbales the selected option
    $("#ddTest option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(this).val('');
    });  

    $("div a.remove").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).attr('rel');
        var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
        //enables the disabled option
        $("#ddTest option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
        //hides the selected option div

     $(this).nextUntil('br').addBack().slideUp(function() { $(this).addClass("hidden"); });
    });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3802bjov/)**

Comment: thank you . but selection is not happening .what to do ?

Comment: what exactly it should behave.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem in either your HTML code.

In your HTML code, the 2nd and 3rd input have been put under one single DIV.

```
<div class="hidden isOption2">
<a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" name="age" >
<br>
<a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" name="age" >
```

And inside your JavaScript, you coded this

```
$("div a.remove").click(function () {
//......
$(this).parent().slideUp(function() { $(this).addClass("hidden"); });
}
```

The `$(this).parent()` in this case is referring to the parent element of the a tag, so in this case, the whole div tag that containing both the input fields will be removed, and the 2 input fields as well.

You could change the HTML code to add another div in order to separate them

```
 <div class="hidden isOption2">
<a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" name="age" >
</div>
<div class="hidden isOption3">
<br>
<a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<label>Age</label>
<input type="text" name="age" >
```

Comment: bro i need one more help . how can i change the option value in selectContainer div ? –

Comment: by default its <option value="Option1">1</option> but i want like this <option value="1">1</option>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Tested it in the StackOverflow fiddler, it works:

HTML:

```
  <div class="selectContainer">
    <label for="name">Number Of Person:</label>
    <select id="ddTest" name="no_person">
      <option value="">- Select -</option>
      <option value="Option1">1</option>
      <option value="Option2">2</option>
      <option value="Option3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden isOption1">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option1">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden isOption2">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden isOption3">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Option3">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age">
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#ddTest").change(function() {
        var value = $("#ddTest option:selected").val();
        if (value === '') {
          return;
        }
        var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

        //displays the selected option div
        theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");

        //disables the selected option
        $("#ddTest option:selected").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).val('');
      });

      $("div a.remove").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('rel');
        var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
        //enables the disabled option
        $("#ddTest option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
        //hides the selected option div
        $(this).parent().slideUp(function() {
          $(this).addClass("hidden");
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```